# How to remove double forward slashes using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have text file that contains some URLs such as this one:

```
https://home.ggg.com/
http://zzz.aaa.net
```

I want to remove the http:// or https:// part from the beginning of each line using sed command but my problem seem in that I do not know how to write the // in the command. It seems needs some additions and not to be written as it is // 
EDIT: please not that some starts with http:// while others with https://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<http\(s\|\):\/\///' file
```

however this is clearer:

```
sed -r 's#\<https?://##' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a different separator:

```
sed 's|https\?://||' filename
```

or

```
sed -r 's|https?://||' filename
```

The `s` is optional here, so it'd remove both `http://` and `https://`.

Use the `g` modifier if you could have more than one pattern in a given line: `'s|https?://||g'`

Comment: Nothing changed. I wrote: echo `https://www.ggg.com | sed 's|https?://||'` and the output was: `https://www.ggg.com`

Comment: `echo 'https://www.ggg.com' | sed 's|https\{0,1\}://||'` for the posix version. Are you using gnu sed or traditionnal posix sed ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu  thnx. Your command worked with me. I use Ubuntu 12.

Comment: @user2192774 In BRE, the `?` needs to be escaped.  See the edit above.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu what is {0,1} for??

Comment: @devnull only NeronLeVelu answer worked. Your answer does not change anything.

Comment: @devnull I was trying to figure out why my version didn't work, could you explain BRE to me (I forgot to escape the ?)

Comment: @MikeH-R `?`, `+`, `{`, `}` aren't special in BRE.  Those are considered as literal characters unless escaped.

Comment: @MikeH-R You may also want to refer to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).

Comment: @user2192774  `{0,1}` mean any occurence of preceding patterne from 0 to 1, the equivalent of `?` in that is not recognize by posix sed but a correct regex (recognize by GNU sed version)